# How to install VirtIO drivers for Winows Server 2008 on KVM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting windows virtio mounted/installed for KVM](https://serverfault.com/questions/452854/getting-windows-virtio-mounted-installed-for-kvm)

I have a KVM vps that has windows server 2008 installed. I want to install VirtIO drivers but I don't know how you would do it on a vps since it has no floppy disk. Can anyone teach me how?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the `virtio-win` iso from http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/bin/. This has all the drivers in it you need.

Note that changes to your VPS server configuration will have to be made to change the disk and  / or network to VirtIO.