# Gnome Boxes on CentOS 7 with Windows 7 as a guest

Tags: centos, windows-7, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I just installed CentOS 7 and tried to use Gnome Boxes to create some virtual machines. As long as I stick to other Linux distributions everything is fine. But I really do have trouble installing Windows 7 or 8 in a box. Boxes does not allow me to mount the VirtIO ISO and it doesn't look like Windows is aware of the virtual controller Boxes uses.

To workaround this I installed RedHat's Virtual Machine Manager. But, unfortunately, I do have the same problem here. I mounted the VirtIO drivers disk on a second IDE CDROM which worked. But, no matter what controller type I use (IDE, SATA, VirtIO), the Windows setup won't use any of the drivers on the disk. It keeps telling me, that there are no suitable drivers on the disk.

Any hints would bei much appreciated.﻿

Comment: It would help if you could show us exactly what's failing and how you configured the VM. See [here](http://serverfault.com/a/452857/126632) for a walkthrough of how this is supposed to go.

Comment: What details do you need exactly? I used the VMM GUI to create the VM and left it to the standard settings in all cases. Nothing fancy. I could post a config file here if this would help.

Comment: Config, screenshots, a more detailed explanation. We are not mind readers and cannot see your screen!

Comment: That's why I said standard settings AKA default configuration. Didn't change a thing. Please see pastebin.com/1hDmRp02 for my config file. I played around with the hard disk controller variants though. But no matter which one I chose the Windows setup program told me that there's no suitable driver.

Comment: OK, where is your more detailed explanation and screenshots?

Comment: A more detailed explanation of what exactly? Which default settings I chose? ;-) No, seriously, I can take screenshots of every Windows setup step but that wouldn't be of any use I suppose. If you could guide me in what details you need exactly? This would be a big help.

Comment: BTW: I looked at the walkthrough. This is exactly how I've done it. But in step 7 my Windows won't install the driver.

Comment: Why won't it install the driver? Come on, you have to give us _something_ to go on here!

Comment: That would be my question. I don't know why it won't install the driver. I did everything exactly as you in your tutorial. The driver installation tells me that the driver can't be installed.

Comment: And that's exactly what I wrote in my original question. I have no idea where anyone would see a reason to give my question a -1. Please see the last sentence of my question: t keeps telling me, that there are no suitable drivers on the disk.

Comment: What can I do to make the drivers compatible with Windows 7? Is this the kind of question you are looking for? Sorry, but I'm out of options here. I can't clarify my question any further as it IS already clear in my opinion what my problem and so my question is. What can I do to make the drivers install?

Comment: You didn't tell us _which_ drivers you tried to install, to begin with. Please come back only when you are ready and willing to share the information that we need to understand your problem.

Comment: Well, ok. I tried to install the drivers for Windows 7 AMD64 which are on the VirtIO drivers disk which I downloaded from KVM's website unter http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers. Those drivers can't be installed.

Comment: Of course those drivers can be installed. I even tried it myself yesterday before I ever replied to you. If you are having a problem installing them, then you need to tell us what the problem is!

Comment: Michael, that's what I don't know and that's what I'm asking here. They definitely can't be installed, otherwise this thread wouldn't exist. I can select the driver's folder and everything but when I'm trying to install them the Windows setup program tells me that it can't find any valid drivers. Meanwhile I tried this with two different versions of the KVM drivers disk, both versions deliver the same result.