# How to switch in ws2012 from an IDE disk to a Virtio disk?

Tags: windows-server-2012, kvm-virtualization, virtio

I am running Windows server 2012 in a virtual machine under Debian Jessie.
I tried to follow the [Red Hat tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/form-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Para_virtualized_drivers-Using_KVM_para_virtualized_drivers_for_existing_devices.html) in order to switch on the Virtio drivers:
1) I downloaded from Debian the [virtio drivers](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/latest-virtio/virtio-win.iso); the current version of the virtio-win.iso is 0.1.110.
2) I shutdowned the vm.
3) I added a new CDROM in virt-manager for the vm. I attached the iso file.
4) I started the vm.
5) In device manager, under storage controllers, I installed a Red Hat Virtio SCSI controller by selecting in the attached CDROM the **viostor** for ws2012.
6) I shutdowned the vm.
7) In virt-manager, I removed the IDE disk and create a new one with the type virtio and with the same .img file.
8) I started the vm.
9) I have a BSOD :-(

What is wrong or what is missing in my procedure ?
Hopes my question is clear ...

Comment: Run [Startup Repair](http://serverfault.com/q/423103/126632). Of course you should have [installed Windows with virtio storage drivers to begin with](http://serverfault.com/q/703675/126632). And [this](http://serverfault.com/a/452857/126632) is how you convert from IDE to virtio after installation.

Comment: the described procedure is for a new installation not for an existing vm ?

Comment: Click the _other_ links.

Comment: Yes , forget my question. The trick was to add a temporary disk !!! what about NetKVM and vioserial: shall I proceed as viostor, I mean add a temp network and a temp serial ?